# the defference between download file through IIS and IIS

Tags: c#, iis, download, response

since we can download file through IIS,like 'http://localhost/test.zip'

why most of people implement the code for download,like

```
if (resHeader == null)
{
    //not Range
    Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
 }
 else
 {
     //Range
     Response.TransmitFile(filePath, resHeader.StartIndex, resHeader.EndIndex - resHeader.StartIndex + 1);
            }
```

Waiting for guide.

Comment: It really depends on whether you would like IIS static file handler to control the downloads or your own code.